# How to use Material Icons as LargeIcon in Android notifications?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to send notifications. How do use Material Icons as [Large icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Templates) in notifications.

I could use drawable resource as large icon, but I would have to create a vector asset for it, and I plan to use a large number of icons and creating one for each is not practical.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem possible. The `largeIcon` takes an `AndroidBitmap` which has a `AndroidBitmapSource`, which is one of three `drawable` `filePath` `byteArray`. Which is sent used to retrieve the image in the platform java code.

The only solution seems to be to add drawable resources you wished to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

For changing notifications icon and sound you have to change icon in src folder of android module [android -> app -> src -> main -> res

also you can define notification text color in your src folder also in res -> values folder